# How to calculate the probability of the parameters?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, parameterization

I am reading the [Wikipedia article on posterior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability) and I note the expression:

$$P(\theta|X) = \frac{P(X|\theta)P(\theta)}{P(X)}$$

I understand that $\theta$ represents the parameters of the probability model underlying $P$.  However, what is actually meant by $P(\theta)$ and how would I calculate this?

In some sense, when I am analyzing data relative to a model, aren't the parameters under my control?  And if so, wouldn't I use something like a uniform distribution for $P(\theta)$?  If the parameters are continuous, wouldn't this value be 0?  How do I connect $P(\theta)$ to ground truth?

Comment: Maybe this https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78629/14346 could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\theta)$ is a *prior*, the assumed distribution of the parameter $\theta$. It is not something that you estimate<sup>1</sup>, but something that describes what you know, or assume, about the parameter *before* seeing the data. If you refuse to make prior assumptions, then you can use so-called "uninformative" priors (e.g. uniform), but [no prior is truly uninformative](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information) (check [here for examples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297901/choosing-between-uninformative-beta-priors/298176#298176) of different "uninformative" priors, that lead to slightly different results). Bayesian would also argue that [you always have and can make some prior assumptions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326484/how-do-bayesian-statistics-handle-the-absence-of-priors/326490#326490). You choose the prior according to your best knowledge, e.g. you know that it should be continuous, positive-valued and skewed, so you choose [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with parameters that fit your assumption (most of the probability mass is centered on the values you consider most likely etc.). As about choosing your priors, check for example the [Eliciting priors from experts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1/eliciting-priors-from-experts) thread.

It is not true that for continuous random variables the prior is zero, the [probability is zero](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142730/px-x-0-when-x-is-continuous-variable), but the [probability density function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok/4223#4223) is non-zero.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Unless you are using [empirical Bayes](http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/) approach, where the priors are estimated from the data.</sub>